# Configure IBM Websphere Mq server and a Java Client to Create SSL Connection

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I need to create a SSL connection between an IBM MQ Qmanager and a Java Client. In order to do that using IBM Key Management GUI,

1. Created key.dkb for QManager and added self-signed certificate to it.
2. Then I extracted that certificate.(cert.arm)
3. Created trustStore.jks file and under signer certificated I added cert.arm   previously extracted.
4. Put the path of key.dkb to Qmanager->SSL and choose suitable ciphersuit.
5. In Java Client added System.property to trustStore.jks.

When I run the program I got an exception as bellow.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host '127.0.0.1(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=127.0.0.1(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:345)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1329)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:863)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1730)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1298)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        ... 25 more
```

Basically this means Qmanager doesn't have certificate signed by trustStore. 
So I guess I have missed something during making selfsigned certificate and truststore.

Can someone help me to create self-signed certificate to establish SSL connection with a java client using IBM Key Management GUI tool?

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the problem going through the [ibm mq troubleshooting guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048145&aid=1)

I just ran mqcertck command in my Qmanager keystore repository and found it hasn't read access to key.kdb. After giving read access using chmod problem solved.

Comment: Normally the key.* files should be owned by mqm with 600 permissions so that only the mqm user can read the key* files.  You can use  `chown mqm:mqm key.*` and `chmod 600 key.*` to accomplish this.